# Me dice que es una variable null siendo que es local

Tags: c#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] Me dice que es una variable null siendo que es local y no se por que

```
 var TarjetaAModificar = new tarjetaDtos
 {
  Id = EntidadId.Value,
  Descripcion = txtDescripcion.Text,
 };
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias brindarnos mas detalles de las propiedades que tiene "tarjetaDtos" y ya verificaste que EntidadId lleve datos?  Por otra parte prueba cambiar "new tarjetaDtos" por "new tarjetaDtos(){...}"

Comment: de casualidad la variable EntidadId permite null? si es asi evaluas si este esta con un valur null en algun lugar? porque alli veo que accedes al EntidadId.Value pero si esta tiene un null asignado fallara justamente con ese mensaje que recibes

Comment: public class tarjetaDtos : BaseDto
    {
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    }

Comment: @luisFalleni te recomiendo que edites la pregunta, remplazando las capturas por el código, sino es sumamente complejo ayudarte

Comment: el problema no esta en la clase tarjetaDtos, el problema es que quieres acceder a una variable EntidadId  que seguro tiene un null como contenido, al usar el Value falla porque no hay nada que devolver al ser null, esto deberias controlarlo en el codigo

Comment: Como te indican otros usuarios, deberías añadir el código en modo texto en lugar de como imágenes. Tal y como está ahora, no se ve bien y es más difícil ayudarte. Además, deberías añadir algo más de información: qué es lo que hace el código, qué resultado esperas y cuál obtienes, qué errores recibes (y dónde). Las preguntas sin un enunciado claro no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: Ya lo solucione no inicialice la variavle EntidadId jaja gracias!!